# Integrate mail_form gem with existing contact form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mail-form

I have a rails 4.2 app with an existing contact form. How would I get rails to send an email to an address with the message in? The mail_form gem looks the most promising but when I try to send an email from the console I get a 'false' message when trying to deliver.

The form is as follows:

```
<%= form_for(enquiry) do |f| %>
  <% if enquiry.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(enquiry.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this enquiry from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% enquiry.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :subject, "Subject:" %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :subject, :size => "40" %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :e_description, "Description:" %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :e_description, :cols => "80", :rows => "10" %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And I've just got the basic ContactForm model from the README:

```
class ContactForm < MailForm::Base
  attribute :customer_name,      :validate => true
  attribute :email,     :validate => /\A([\w\.%\+\-]+)@([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,})\z/i

  attribute :message

  # Declare the e-mail headers. It accepts anything the mail method
  # in ActionMailer accepts.
  def headers
    {
      :subject => "My Contact Form",
      :to => "my.email@gmail.com",
      :from => %("#{customer_name}" <#{email}>)
    }
  end
end
```

Edit - Enquiries Controller:

```
class EnquiriesController < ApplicationController

def index
    @enquiries = Enquiry.all
end

def show
end

def new
    @enquiry = Enquiry.new
    render 'pages/contactus'
end

def edit
end

def create
    @enquiry = Enquiry.new(enquiry_params)
    if current_user.customer?
        @enquiry.user_id = current_user.id
    end
    if @enquiry.save
        redirect_to '/pages/contactus', notice: 'Enquiry was successfully sent.'
    else
        render :new
    end
end

def update
    if @enquiry.update(enquiry_params)
        redirect_to @enquiry, notice: 'Enquiry was successfully updated.'
    else
        render :edit
    end
end

def destroy
    @enquiry.destroy
    redirect_to enquiries_url, notice: 'Enquiry was successfully destroyed.'
end

private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_enquiry
    @enquiry = Enquiry.find(params[:id])
end

# If resource not found redirect to root and flash error.
def resource_not_found
    yield
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Room not found."
end

# Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
def enquiry_params
    params.require(:enquiry).permit(:subject, :e_description, :user_id)
end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :e_description, "Description:" %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :e_description, :cols => "80", :rows => "10" %>
  </div>
```

I assume this is the content of your email. The form is calling it e_description, while in your ContactForm class I see a reference to message on line 5. Make them the same.

Adding the controller code would assist with further analysis.

Another issue is the reference to 'email' on line 13 (which should generate an error as it should be included within the quotes.) Try;

```
:from => "#{customer_name} <#{email}>"
```

Comment: I've added in the controller code. It currently doesn't seem to be doing anything.

Comment: Working from the assumption your form and your class now both refer to :message, is your enquiry_params method referring to the same :message attribute?